# How to configure a proxy with socat that listens for MQTT connections

Tags: linux, mqtt, portforwarding, socat

I'm trying to capture MQTT traffic between a client and a subscriber, and I want intercept this traffic using socat. I know that my broker is running on port 1883 of my localhost, so what I do after connecting the broker, the client and the subscriber is:

`socat -v TCP4-LISTEN:9000 TCP4:localhost:1883`

The problem is that nothing shows up when i try to publish a message with
`mosquitto_pub -t "test" -h localhost -m "message"`.

The output from `lsof -i` is:

```
mosquitto 1605 jaqen 5u IPv6 28209 0t0 TCP localhost:56422->localhost:1883 (ESTABLISHED) socat 1676 jaqen 5u IPv4 29081 0t0 TCP *:9999 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: You've limited that to just IPv4, it's perfectly possible the clients are talking to `::1` as localhost. `lsof -i` will tell you if that's the case

Comment: Also [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66798833/edit) the question to show how you've configured the client, e.g. are you using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I'm using localhost, for the client subscriber i did 'mosquitto_sub -t "test" -h localhost', for the publisher 'mosquitto_pub -t "test" -h localhost -m "message"'. The message is correctly passed between them

Comment: Yes, but `localhost` can resolve to both `127.0.0.1` and `::1`, if it's the latter then socat won't see it as it's only looking for IPv4. You've also not told those commands to use port `9000`

Comment: no localhost points to 127.0.0.1, you have centered my problem, i don't understand how to show the messages using port 9000

Comment: mosquitto 1605 jaqen    5u  IPv6  28209      0t0  TCP localhost:56422->localhost:1883 (ESTABLISHED)
socat     1676 jaqen    5u  IPv4  29081      0t0  TCP *:9999 (LISTEN)

Comment: This is the result of lsof -i

Comment: Try `mosquitto_pub -t "test" -h localhost -p 9000 -m "message"` (SOCAT is listening on port 9000 so you need to tell `mosquitto_pub` to use that port; it defaults to 1883 so will connect directly to the broker without a `-p`).